# play framework bootstrap multiple inputtext in one line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I want to create a form with multiple input text boxes in one line, with placeholder text and w/o any labels. Currently I am using the standard bootstrap constructor like below. But it creates all the input text boxes on separate lines with labels.

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)
<div class="control-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
<placeholder class="control-placeholder" for="@elements.id">@elements.placeholder</placeholder>
<div class="controls">@elements.input
    <p class="help-inline">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</p>
    @if(elements.hasErrors) { <p class="help-block">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</p> }
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a template to create the controls in just one line?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use helper to create the form fields, it's just helpers...

Instead create common HTML fields and optionally set value from Form if required. if you don't know how to, let me know. I'll post some sample.

Comment: Could you post an example? I want to be able to be able to: 1. bind the input boxes to form 2. Show validation errors 3. Do these things for array of controls. I am using @repeat helper to achieve that. Thanks.